# Ubuntu Get's Logout Automatically, After Installation

Tags: software-installation, logout

I have recently installed Ubuntu on my Virtual Box. When I run Ubuntu, it works fine but when I open a terminal and Try to install any thing or try to update it by typing `sudo apt update`, I automatically get logout  .

Comment: try running the software updater tool, and let it install updates, and then reboot. You should be able to find software updater by searching for that name.

Comment: @shmu Is software updater different then apt update? Sorry if this sounds too basic as i am new so that's why asking.

Comment: It does more than that one command you tried. Something is not working right on your system and updating sometimes sets things right.